# Randomly moving object on JavaFx does not stop for bounds

Tags: java, javafx, collision

There are two primary issues, one would be that the code always detects that enemy characters are colliding almost all of the time on the x-axis. Another issue would be that on the code that I tried that doesn't collide all the time on the x-axis, the enemy movement doesn't follow the rules of being bounded within the play area.

```
private void randomMovement(Rectangle enemy) {
    
    double currX = enemy.getX();
    double currY = enemy.getY();

    double randX = random.nextInt(5) * (random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1) *(this.playerComponent.returnX()>enemy.getX() ? 2.5 : -2.5);
    double randY = random.nextInt(5) * (random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1) * (this.playerComponent.returnY()>enemy.getY() ? 2.5 : -2.5);

    double newX = enemy.getX() + randX;
    double newY = enemy.getY() + randY;

    enemy.setX(newX);
    enemy.setY(newY);

    double enemyMaxX = newX + enemy.getWidth();
    double enemyMaxY = newY + enemy.getHeight();
    double xmin = this.playArea.getX();
    double xmax = this.playArea.getX() + this.playArea.getWidth();
    double ymin = this.playArea.getY();
    double ymax = this.playArea.getY() + this.playArea.getHeight();
        
    if(newX < xmin) {
        enemy.setX(xmin);
    }

    if(enemyMaxX > xmax) {
        enemy.setX(xmax-enemy.getWidth());
    }

    if(newY < ymin) {
        enemy.setY(ymin);
    }

    if(enemyMaxY > ymax) {
        enemy.setY(ymax-enemy.getHeight());
    }
}
```

I have tried to see if there really is a collision all the time by decreasing the x positions of the enemy shapes on collision detection, and they all move to the left. Fixing this issue by separating the code as much as I can, I run into the original issue of the shapes not stopping for the right and bottom bounds.

Comment: Create an  [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/2423906).

Comment: What node is the parent of each enemy?  What node is the parent of `playArea`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows a ball(circle) stopping when coming in contact with a wall(rectangle). The key is understanding that once a collision is detected, the ball may have entered the wall. You should determine if the ball has entered the wall and move it back to the point right before it hits the wall.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    Circle ball = new Circle(100, 375, 10, Color.GREEN);
    Rectangle wall = new Rectangle(365, 325, 20, 100);
    Timeline gameLoop;        
            
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        wall.setFill(Color.BLUE);       

        gameLoop = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                     moveBall();
                     checkCollision();
        }));
        gameLoop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
       
        Pane middleRoot = new Pane(ball, wall);
        middleRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        middleRoot.setPrefSize(750, 750);
        Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
        btnStart.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(gameLoop.getStatus() == Timeline.Status.STOPPED)
            {
                gameLoop.play();
            }
        });        
    
        Button btnReset = new Button("Reset");
        btnReset.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(gameLoop.getStatus() == Timeline.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                gameLoop.stop();
                ball.setCenterX(100);               
            }
        });
        
        HBox bottomRoot = new HBox(btnStart, btnReset);
        VBox root = new VBox(middleRoot, bottomRoot);
        
        var scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
    public void moveBall()
    {
        ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() + 3);
    }
    
    public void checkCollision()
    {
        //If you find a collision, find out how far past the wall boundary did the ball go. Once you have that distance, move the ball back to that distance amount.         
        if(Shape.intersect(ball, wall).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1)
        {
            double xDelta = wall.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() - (ball.getCenterX() + ball.getRadius());
            ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() + xDelta);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]