# Move Rectangle Up and Down

Tags: javafx

I'm really new to javafx and I am doing an assignment on it for class. I have to basically create a simple animation where the rectangle vertically bounces up and down when it reaches the top and bottom of the window. However, I have been struggling with doing this, I've looked up any tutorials that could help me, but everything I've tried from using EventHandlers, if statements, and instance variables to change the direction did not work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;

public class Main extends Application
{
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50);
rect.setX(0);
rect.setY(10);


Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(rect);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
primaryStage.setTitle("A Simple Scene!");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();


Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> {

rect.setY(rect.getY() + 1);


}));


timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();

timeline.setRate(60);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
```

It is confusing to an extent, but I want to be able to understand how this kind of animation works so I can learn and do it myself. Advice or help of any kind would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#BEIIJJJB)?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641068/2423906) can help. When the collision is detected, move the ball in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideas in this code should help you develop your code. I altered the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641068/2423906). The key is to use `Timeline` or `AnimationTimer` to create a game loop. Use the game loop to move the object and when that object reaches its root node's bound, change the object's direction.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    Circle ball = new Circle(100, 375, 10, Color.GREEN);
    
    Timeline gameLoop;        
            
    double leftBound = 0.0;
    double rightbound;
    double ballVelocity = 10;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        gameLoop = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                     moveBall();
                     checkWallCollision();
        }));
        gameLoop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
       
        Pane middleRoot = new Pane(ball);
        middleRoot.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
            if(newWidth != null)
            {
                rightbound = newWidth.doubleValue();
            }
        });
        middleRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        middleRoot.setPrefSize(750, 750);
        Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
        btnStart.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(gameLoop.getStatus() == Timeline.Status.STOPPED)
            {
                gameLoop.play();
            }
        });        
    
        Button btnReset = new Button("Reset");
        btnReset.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(gameLoop.getStatus() == Timeline.Status.RUNNING)
            {
                gameLoop.stop();
                ball.setCenterX(100);               
            }
        });
        
        HBox bottomRoot = new HBox(btnStart, btnReset);
        VBox root = new VBox(middleRoot, bottomRoot);
        
        var scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
    public void moveBall()
    {
        ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() + ballVelocity);
    }
    
    public void checkWallCollision()
    {        
        //If the ball hits the wall, change its direction
        if(ball.getCenterX() + ball.getRadius() >= rightbound || ball.getCenterX() - ball.getRadius() <= leftBound)
        {
            ballVelocity = ballVelocity * -1;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I understand it much better now!